# SpringDoc is duplicating all paths under one tag

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui, springdoc-ui

we have just moved from swaggercodegen to openapigenerator and we have also moved to springdoc instead of springfox.

We realized that for all our swagger.json files, the springdoc that we view has one tag in which all other paths are also duplicated.

For e.g.

- Tag1

Path b

- Tag2 (only this tag has a description - The Tag1 api)

Path a

Path b

Path c

Path d

- Tag3

Path d

The api/v3/docs that the ui points to shows Tag1 for Path b and Path d even though such is not the case in the Swagger.json we have created. We have also moved from spring boot 2.5 to spring boot 3.x.

We used useTags under our openapi generator configs, we also tried setting springdoc.auto-tag-classes to false. We also tried adding an empty Tag4 which didnt show up at all.